# Fallo en una expresión regular con preg_match PHP

Tags: php, regex, csv

Estoy realizando un programa, recorriendo un array con eans (ids formados por 13 dígitos) y tengo que limpiarlo de eans incorrectos. En este caso, lo que estoy intentando es quitar los eans que sólo tienen un 0. Sin embargo, me siguen apareciendo y no me los está filtrando el programa. Aquí el código:

```
if( !preg_match("/^[0]{1}$/", $arrayLineasLimpio){
 $arrayLineasLimpisimo[]=$arrayLineasLimpio;
}
```

Ese código está enmarcado dentro de un while que recorre el CSV dónde están originalmente los eans, así que no hay problema. El tema es que hago un var_dump de $arrayLineasLimpisimo[] y me muestra 0, no me lo filtra. ¿Dónde puedo estar fallando? Gracias.

PRUEBAS DE LO QUE ES UN EAN CORRECTO:

```
8423490264899
8623193912482
7361847428123
```

PRUEBAS DE LO QUE ES UN EAN INCORRECTO:

```
0
0       (no se ve, pero con espacios a la derecha)
```

Importante mencionar que todos los valores que estoy comparando son Strings, es decir: quiero quitar dígitos pero en el programa son strings, igual viene por ahí el fallo, pero el tema es que en la BBDD al final son VARCHAR, de ahí que esté trabajando así.

ACTUALIZACIÓN 1:

He cambiado la lógica a fin de intentar hacer el filtro lo más entendible y limpio posible. Aquí el código:

```
$archivo=fopen("articulos_erp.csv", "r"); //abro el archivo   
$arrayLineasDefinitivo=array();


while(!feof($archivo)){ //Voy leyendo el CSV

    $linea=utf8_encode(fgets($archivo)); //Leo datos con CSV y lo voy poniendo en formato UTF8
    $arrayLineas=explode(";", $linea); //Aquí tengo mi array con los datos del CSV

    if(!empty($arrayLineas[0])){ //Con esto quito cuando el ean esté vacío
        if(!preg_match("/[A-Za-z]/", $arrayLineas[0])){ //Con esto quito los ean que tengan alguna letra
                if(!preg_match("/,/", $arrayLineas[0])){ //Con esto quito las comas
                   
                    $arrayLineasSinEspacios=trim($arrayLineas[0]);
                    $arrayLineasLimpio=str_replace(" ", "", $arrayLineasSinEspacios);
                    $numeroCaracteres=strlen($arrayLineasLimpio);
                    $arrayDigitosDeterminado=array();
                    $arrayLineasLimpisimo=array();
                    $arrayDigitosFinal=array();

                    if(strlen($arrayLineasLimpio)==13||strlen($arrayLineasLimpio)==12||strlen($arrayLineasLimpio)==11){
                        if(!empty($arrayLineasLimpio))
                            $arrayDigitosDeterminado=$arrayLineasLimpio;
                            $numerodigitos=strlen($arrayDigitosDeterminado);
                            // var_dump($numerodigitos);
                

                            switch($numerodigitos){

                                case 13:
                                    $arrayLineasLimpisimo=$arrayDigitosDeterminado;
                                    break;
                                case 12:
                                    $arrayLineasLimpisimo="0".$arrayDigitosDeterminado;
                                    break;
                                case 11:
                                    $arrayLineasLimpisimo="00".$arrayDigitosDeterminado;
                                    break;  

                                }
                                    
                                echo "<pre>";
                                var_dump($arrayLineasLimpisimo);
                                echo "<br>";
                                echo "</pre>"; 

                                $valorEan=substr($arrayLineasLimpisimo, 0, 4);

                                if($valorEan!=0000){
                                    $arrayDigitosFinal=$arrayLineasLimpisimo;
                                        echo "<pre>";
                                        var_dump($arrayDigitosFinal);
                                        echo "SE REPITE";
                                        echo "<br>";
                                        echo "</pre>";
                                }



                            }

      
                    }

Ahora mismo el problema es que me debería filtrar valores como "0000000000577" o como "0000012009100". Ejemplos de eans correctos son "8431125120052" o "8427507127078". Estoy ahora bloqueado con esto pero no veo el fallo. Gracias.
```

Comment: Podrias mostar un ejemplo de un "eans" incorrecto, y uno correcto para poder realizar una expresion regular, y realizar pruebas, ya que estamos a ciegas.

Comment: te sobran las comillas dobles, se trata de una regular expresion se escapa y ya esta

Comment: Ya he puesto eans de ejemplo. En cuanto a las comillas dobles, ¿cómo se escapan? Gracias.

Comment: Que significa el / al principio?

Comment: El "/" marca tanto el principio como el final de la expresión regular. Es simplemente una convención. Las expresiones regulares se escriben entre "/".

Comment: Puedes mostrar el while donde recorres el CSV

Comment: Puesto y he actualizado el código. Gracias :)

Comment: @Sergio en qué te estás basando para decir que `0000000000577` es inválido? ¿Cuál sería la validación que querrías usar en este caso? ¿En qué se diferencia del resto?

Comment: Por lo que veo si usas la regular expresion de mi solucion, veras que obtienes en numero X de veces que sale el 0, con eso te valdria no? o cual es el problema? En cualquier caso cual es la regla de validacion?

Answer (score 0):

Ya está solucionado. El problema al final era una tontería. Observemos el código:

```
                                echo "<pre>";
                                var_dump($arrayLineasLimpisimo);
                                echo "<br>";
                                echo "</pre>"; 

                                $valorEan=substr($arrayLineasLimpisimo, 0, 4);

                                if($valorEan!=0000){
                                    $arrayDigitosFinal=$arrayLineasLimpisimo;
                                        echo "<pre>";
                                        var_dump($arrayDigitosFinal);
                                        echo "SE REPITE";
                                        echo "<br>";
                                        echo "</pre>";
                                }
```

Estoy imprimiendo tanto código que ya filtra los 0 como código que no. De ahí que se me juntaran al imprimir ambas salidas de código y pensara que no funcionara, pero sí funciona.

Answer (score -1):

cambia

```
 if( !preg_match("/^[0]{1}$/", $arrayLineasLimpio){
     $arrayLineasLimpisimo[]=$arrayLineasLimpio;
}
```

por:

```
if( !preg_match("/[0]{1}/", $arrayLineasLimpio){
     $arrayLineasLimpisimo[]=$arrayLineasLimpio;
}
```

esos caracteres marcan inicio y principio, tu quieres que te analice todo el texto.
te dejo una pagina muy utli: https://regex101.com/

Comment: estaría muy bien que el negativo aportara una explicación o comentario!

Comment: Si te fijas esta respuesta se realizo antes de la edicion del OP!